# apache running different sites for different urls

Tags: apache-2.2

What would i have to do (perhaps to virtualhost directive) to run www.example.com/link1 from /var/www/link1, and www.example.com/link2 from /home/name/link2?

All the stuff i've seen online is about running different domains, can someone point me to the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would:

```
Alias /link1 /var/www/link1
Alias /link2 /home/name/link2
```

Be sufficient?